# Literature and Table of Contents

Tags: page-numbering

I realized that page number of Literature in Table of Contents is wrong, i.e. displays page number of last page of references instead of first page of references (clicking on this number leads to first page of ref.)

```
\documentclass{harvard-thesis}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatura}

% the front matter
\input{frontmatter/coverpage}
\maketitle
\copyrightpage
\abstractpage
\tableofcontents
%\authorlist
\listoffigures
\dedicationpage
\acknowledgments

\include{chapters/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2}

\clearpage
\bibliography{literatura}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literatura}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-fr}


\end{document}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Здраво, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Dear LaRiFaRi, I edited code and added other details.

Comment: You are adding the entry to the toc when all of the bibliography is done, put the `addcontentsline` *before* `bibliography`.